# Selecting correct multilib version for linker automatically

Tags: gcc

I am using GCC to compile a program for an **Atmel Cortex M4 SAM4S** Processor. I need to link the standard libraries libgcc.a and libc.a, and to do so I am currently using the following makefile commands

```
LIBDIR1=C:/Program\ Files\ \(x86\)/GNU\ Arm\ Embedded\ Toolchain/10\ 2020-q4-major/arm-none-eabi/lib/thumb/v7e-m/nofp
LIBDIR2=C:/Program\ Files\ \(x86\)/GNU\ Arm\ Embedded\ Toolchain/10\ 2020-q4-major/lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/10.2.1/thumb/v7e-m/nofp

ld_input=linker.ld startup.o main.o syscalls.o
ld_flags=-L$(LIBDIR1) -L$(LIBDIR2) -lm -lc -lgcc

out.elf: $(ld_input)
    arm-none-eabi-ld -o out.elf -T $(ld_input) $(ld_flags)
```

However, to link to the correct multilib, I need to specify the subdirectories /thumb/v7e-m/nofp explicitly, which I determined via

```
arm-none-eabi-gcc -mcpu=cortex-m4 --print-multi-dir
```

Is there a way to link to the correct subdirectories automatically, based on the `-mcpu=cortex-m4` option?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems everything works by using gcc instead of ld for linking. gcc then calls the linker with all the correct options, including all the standard librarier automatically.

The code shown in the question can be replaced by

```
ld_input=linker.ld startup.o main.o syscalls.o

out.elf: $(ld_input)
    arm-none-eabi-gcc -mcpu=cortex-m4 -o out.elf -T $(ld_input)
```